Flutter: PlatformException when trying to get Google Sign-In access token
I'm experiencing an issue with Google Sign-In in my Flutter application. When attempting to sign in with Google, I receive a PlatformException. Here's the error log:
W/Auth    (10169): [GoogleAuthUtil] [GoogleAuthUtil] error status:UNKNOWN with method:getTokenWithDetails
...
I/flutter (10169): error: PlatformException(exception, ERROR, null, null)
E/flutter (10169): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(exception, ERROR, null, null)
E/flutter (10169): #0 GoogleSignInApi.getAccessToken (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:250:7)
E/flutter (10169): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10169): #1 GoogleSignInAndroid.getTokens.<anonymous closure> (package:google_sign_in_android/google_sign_in_android.dart:68:15)
E/flutter (10169): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10169): #2 GoogleSignInAccount.authentication (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:95:9)
E/flutter (10169): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10169): #3 GoogleLoginProvider.getAuthCredential (package:firebase_manager/src/auth/login/providers/google_login_provider.dart:15:11)
E/flutter (10169): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10169): #4 LoginTool.loginByGoogle (package:firebase_manager/src/auth/login/login_tool.dart:36:37)
E/flutter (10169): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10169): #5 StatePage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:saiwai/ui/loginpage/login_page.dart:80:42)
E/flutter (10169): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10169):

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Updated all dependencies to their latest versions
Checked and updated the SHA-1 fingerprint in the Firebase console
Verified the Firebase configuration files (google-services.json)
flutter clean

Despite these efforts, the error persists. I'm using the latest stable version of Flutter and testing on an Android device.
Here's a snippet of my code where the error occurs:
  Future<OAuthCredential?> getAuthCredential() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      // Obtain the auth details from the request
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      // Create a new credential
      return GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this issue or how to further diagnose and resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have you tried debugging the code and seeing that the arguments sent to the GoogleAuthProvider are valid?

This worked for me
GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleSignInAuthentication =
    await (await GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: ["profile", "email"],
).signIn())
    ?.authentication;


thank you, it works
somehow it seems scopes is required now, my app suddenly crash when sign in with google even it is live on play store and works so well before

Awesome, adding the scopes helped in my code, too. It also seems to be necessary just for physical devices, on my emulator it's still working

similar problem, yesterday this code still worked, today it doesn't, in all my applications that I haven't updated for several months with this code they show an error:
static Future<void> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Check your internet connection and try again.')),
        );
        return;
      }

      await googleSignIn.signOut();

      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      log('Google User: ${googleUser?.email}');

      if (googleUser == null) {
        log('Google Sign-In canceled');
        return;
      }

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      log('Google Authentication: ${googleAuth.accessToken}, ${googleAuth.idToken}');

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      log('Google Credentials: ${credential.providerId}');

      final UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        await addUserToFirestore(user);

        if (context.mounted) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
        log('FirebaseAuthException: ${e.code} - ${e.message}');
      } else if (e is PlatformException) {
        log('PlatformException: ${e.code} - ${e.message} - ${e.details}');
      } else {
        log('Error during Google Sign-In: $e');
      }
      if (context.mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Login error: ${e.toString()}')),
        );
      }
    }
  }

[log] PlatformException: exception - ERROR - null

Expanding on Akshat Baranwal's comment, if you are using Google Sign In new method with Google Provider you must add "scopes" in GoogleProvider:
SignInScreen(
   providers: [
     GoogleProvider(
       scopes: ["profile", "email"], // add this line
       clientId: "your_client_ID"),
   ],
 );


We just encountered the same issue.
This issue can also occur due to invalid keys in firebase
first check those
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'   ]);

Adding these in scopes will solve it.

For now, it's work for me by adding:
GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: ["profile", "email"],
)

Check this GitHub issue for more background:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/155429
